# Domain monotonicity - $\mu_n (\Omega_2) \leq \mu_n (\Omega_1)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

From the article [Weyl's law](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/weyl_law.pdf) of Matt Stevenson page $3$, there's a lemma where I'd like some help to understand the proof.

> **Lemma. (Domain Monotonicity)** If $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2$, then $\mu_n(\Omega_2) \leq \mu_n (\Omega_1)$.
>
> *Pf :* Remark that $H_0^1 (\Omega_1) \subset H_0^1 (\Omega_2)$, so $\Phi_n(H_0^1 (\Omega_1)) \subset \Phi_n(H_0^1 (\Omega_2)).$ Then by the
>   version $2$ of the Minimax Principle, we conclude that $\mu_n
>  (\Omega_2) \leq \mu_n (\Omega_1)$

I know that we could extend continuously every eigenfunction of $\Omega_1$ by vanishing on $\Omega_2$, i.e

$$ w'(x) = \begin{cases} 
      w(x) & x \in \Omega_1 \\
      0 & x \in \Omega_2 - \Omega_1 \\
   \end{cases}. $$

However, I do not see the order relation between $\mu_n(\Omega_2) = \inf_{X \in \Phi_n(V)} \sup_{u \in X} \frac{\|\nabla u(\Omega_2)\|^2}{\|u(\Omega_2)\|^2}$ and $\mu_n(\Omega_1) = \inf_{X \in \Phi_n(V)} \sup_{u \in X} \frac{\|\nabla u(\Omega_1)\|^2}{\|u(\Omega_1)\|^2}$ and how to explain that.

> **Edit :**
>
> Let  $$R_n(H^1_0) = \{\sup_{u\in X^n}\rho(u)\ |\
>  X\in\Phi_n(H^1_0)\}.$$  Notice that $R$ is the image of a function
>   $\Phi_n(H)\to\mathbb{R}$ taking $X\mapsto\sup_{u\in X}\mathcal{R}(u)$.
>   As $\Phi_n(H^1_0 (\Omega_1))\subset\Phi_n(H^1_0 (\Omega_2))$, we have
>   that $R_n(H^1_0 (\Omega_1))\subseteq R_n(H^1_0 (\Omega_2))$. From this fact, by the comment of Renart, we are sur that $\inf (R_n(H^1_0 (\Omega_1))) \geq \inf(R_n(H^1_0 (\Omega_2)))$. By the Minimax principle, it is clear that $\mu_n(\Omega_1) \geq \mu_n(\Omega_2)$.

**Question :** Could anyone be able to explain rigorously that relation?

**Question :** If we proceed by contradiction, why is it not possible to get $\mu_n(\Omega_2) = \inf_{X \in \Phi_n(V)} \sup_{u \in X} \frac{\|\nabla u(\Omega_2)\|^2}{\|u(\Omega_2)\|^2} > \mu_n(\Omega_1) = \inf_{X \in \Phi_n(V)} \sup_{u \in X} \frac{\|\nabla u(\Omega_1)\|^2}{\|u(\Omega_1)\|^2}$ ?

Comment: If $A\subset B \subset \mathbf R$ then $\inf A \geq \inf B$, it's that simple.

Comment: @Renart I have edited my question, could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Which relation do you mean by "that relation"?\

Comment: (Reference to [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247465/why-the-minimax-principle-says-that-nu-n-is-given-by-minimizing-the-same-expr/247467?noredirect=1#comment608385_247467).)

Comment: @Neal I talk about the  order relation or the inequality if you want

Comment: @CHSLD I recommend pinpointing exactly which part of the argument I offered you do not understand, and then editing your question to specifically refer to where your understanding breaks down.